# Acrobat javascript ComboBox and Text Field

Tags: javascript, combobox, acrobat

Hi I have a pdf form with multiple `ComboBoxes`.  If the user selects option 1 or Option 5, an `app.alert` message is displayed informing the user to enter further justification in a text field.  However, when the user enters the text in the text field, the `app.alert` message still appears.  How can I stop the message from displaying when the user enters texts in the text field?  The code for the textfield is located under the Calculate tab Custom calculation script:

```
var v = getField("ComboBox14").value;
var n = "N/A";
var g = getField ("Justification").value;
var x = "You selected OPTION " + v + ":  Further justification is    required; please enter it here.";
if (v == "1" || v == "5")
{ 
    app.alert (x);
    event.rc = false;
    getField("Justification").setFocus();
}
else if (v == "2" || v == "3" || v =="4")
{
   event.value = n;
}
```

Comment: RESOLVED!  I removed the script from the Custom Calculation Script and moved it to the Actions -> onBlur ->Run a Javascript and included in the if statement if(v == "1" || v == "5" && g == "")

Comment: Just to verify if it really solved the issue: select a combo box value of 2, 3, or 4, and then click in the Justification field; does it show the correct value after you clicked?

Comment: Hi Max, Yes the correct values is displayed 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) after I've clicked.   Adding && g == "" to the first if statement made it work.